# Show message after activating WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to display an activation message after activating the plugin.

I've seen a few questions on SO about this, but none of 'em work properly:

```
if (!get_option("startup")) {
    echo "<div class='updated'><h3>Welcome to [name]</h3>";
    update_option('startup', 'true');
}
```

That works.. kinda. It puts the HTML at the very top, even before the `<!DOCTYPE>`. Is there any way to put it at the right place? So in the body tag?

Comment: did you tried to call it in the right place?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a few things you'll need to do here. Firstly, the [`register_activation_hook()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/) is used to hook into the activation of your plugin. And the [`admin_notices` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) is used to add a notice inside the admin area (you can't just print your notice out anywhere).

However, there's an additional complication in that you *can't* use the `admin_notices` action on plugin activation. This is because WordPress doesn't 'live activate' your plugin - it activates it in the background and suppresses the output in order to make sure, before completing the activation, that it doesn't trigger any fatal errors.

Fortunately, [this blog post](https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-admin-notice-on-plugin-activation/) outlines a solution to this problem. The author of the post suggests using [transients](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to save the 'state' of your plugin so that it can be retrieved once it has been activated.

Because that blog has a CC-BY-SA license like this site, I'll copy the code in here so it lives on. I've slightly condensed it to keep the length of this post down, but you can [view the whole blog post](https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-admin-notice-on-plugin-activation/) for the full solution. I've also tested this to ensure it still works - and it does on my install of WordPress 4.5.3.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'fx_admin_notice_example_activation_hook' );

function fx_admin_notice_example_activation_hook() {
    set_transient( 'fx-admin-notice-example', true, 5 );
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'fx_admin_notice_example_notice' );

function fx_admin_notice_example_notice(){

    /* Check transient, if available display notice */
    if( get_transient( 'fx-admin-notice-example' ) ){
        ?>
        <div class="updated notice is-dismissible">
            <p>Thank you for using this plugin! <strong>You are awesome</strong>.</p>
        </div>
        <?php
        /* Delete transient, only display this notice once. */
        delete_transient( 'fx-admin-notice-example' );
    }
}
```